# Spacebetween container in a Row not working

Tags: flutter

Basically I'm trying to place a space between 2 container with the following codes so each But mainAxisAlignment widget is not working. Both container are sticked to each other at the start

```
Positioned(
                  bottom: 10,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[                   
                      Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: Text(product.name,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)))),

                      Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: Text(
                                  '${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, _startingPrice, discount: product.discount, discountType: product.discountType, asFixed: 1)}'
                                  '${_endingPrice != null ? ' - ${PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, _endingPrice, discount: product.discount, discountType: product.discountType, asFixed: 1)}' : ''}',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))))
                    ],
                  )
                  ),
```

Comment: Are the containers filling the row? Also, an easy way to add a space would be to wrap the containers in a Padding widget or insert a SizedBox(width:10.0) between the containers

Answer (score 0):

Just Assign width to Positioned widget

see below

```
 Positioned(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // <- Add this line (width == screen_width)
     bottom: 10,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                   // widget 1
                   // widget 2
                 ]
 );
```

Comment: Thanks mate, exactly how I wanted to appear.